# Assigning people to projects

Tags: combinatorics

Here is a problem I recently stumbled at:

> There are 10 people and 5 different projects. Each person needs to
>   take part in exactly 3 different projects. Prove or disprove that
>   average number of people assigned to a project needs to be 6.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let $a_1, \ldots, a_5$ be the number of people on the projects. Then $\sum_{i = 1}^5 a_i = 30$. Therefore the average is $\frac15 \sum_{i = 1}^5 a_i = 6$.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the ten people has $3$ projects on his/her metaphorical plate. This means the ten plates together have $30$ people-project assignments. But there are $5$ different projects, so the *average* number of people per project is $$\frac{30}{5}=6$$